# If $\alpha \in E$ is separable, then $F[\alpha]$ is a separable extension

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

Let $F \subseteq E$ be an extension field.

A polynomial $f\in F[x]$ is separable if every irreducible factor of $f$ has distinct roots.
An element $\alpha \in E$ is separable if the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $F$ is separable. An extension field $E$ is separable if every element in $E$ is separable.

**My question is as follows:** Let $\alpha \in E$ be a separable element. I want to prove or disprove that $F[\alpha]$ is a separable extension.

Comment: The cubic root of 2 comes to mind.

Comment: @AsafKaragila : What do you mean ? I think it follows from $F(\alpha)$ be contained in $K/F$ such that $F = K^G$ (the fixed field of $G$) where $G = Aut(K/F)$

Comment: It's true. See section V.4 of Lang's *Algebra*.

Comment: The result is true, and even more: $F(\alpha_1,\ldots \alpha_n)$ is a separable extension iff each $\alpha_i$ is separable over $F$. See: http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/galoistheory/separable1.pdf

Comment: @AsafKaragila I presume you were talking about $\mathbb Q(\sqrt[3]{2})$ over $\mathbb Q$. Note that any field of characteristic $0$ is perfect, so by default any extension of a field of characteristic $0$ is separable.

Answer (score 1):

One way (but perhaps not the best way) to prove this is using Galois theory. First, one proves the following theorem (see page 42 of Patrick Morandi's *Field and Galois Theory*):

> **Theorem 4.9.** *Let $K$ be an algebraic extension of $F$. Then the following statements are equivalent:*
>
> 1. *$K$ is Galois over $F$.*
> 2. *$K$ is normal and separable over $F$.*
> 3. *$K$ is a splitting field of a set of separable polynomials over $F$.*

Patrick Morandi defines $K$ to be Galois over $F$ if $F = \mathcal{F}(\operatorname{Gal}(K/F))$, where $\operatorname{Gal}(K/F)$ is the set of all $F$-automorphisms of $K$.

Then, as a corollary (see page 44) we get the required result. Here's a proof of the result assuming the above theorem:

Let $E/F$ be an extension of fields and let $\alpha \in E$ be separable over $F$. Then, $\min(F,\alpha)$ is separable. If $K$ is a splitting field of $F$ contained in an algebraic closure of $E$, then $K/F$ is normal and separable by the above theorem. Since $F \subset F(\alpha) \subset K$, $F(\alpha)$ is also separable over $F$.

(Remark: since $\alpha$ is algebraic over $F$, $F[\alpha] = F(\alpha)$.)

---

In fact, the same method of proof allows one to show that if $\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n \in E$ are separable over $F$, then $F(\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n)$ is separable over $F$. Simply let $K$ be the splitting field of the set of separable polynomials $\{ \min(F,\alpha_i) : 1 \leq i \leq n \}$. Then, $K$ is normal and separable over $F$ by the theorem, and so, $F(\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n)$ is separable over $F$.

Answer (score 0):

Fix an algebraic closure $\overline{K[\alpha]}$ (or just fix the splitting field of $P_{min,\alpha,K}(X)$). As $\alpha$ is separable this means its minimal polynomial has degree $>0$ and has only simple roots, now consider the $K-$endomorphism $[\cdot\alpha]:K[\alpha]\longrightarrow K[\alpha]$ consisting of multiplying by $\alpha$ and consider $P_{min,[\cdot\alpha],K}(X)$ it is easy to show (if one decide to take such minimal polynomial their monic version) that $P_{min,[\cdot\alpha],K}(X)=P_{min,\alpha,K}(X)$, hence $P_{min,[\cdot\alpha],K}(X)$ has only simple roots, this means equivalently that $[\cdot\alpha]\in End_{K}(K[\alpha])$ is diagonalizable i.e. that there exist a basis $\mathcal{B}\in \overline{K[\alpha]}^{[K[\alpha]:K]}$  such that $mat_{\mathcal{B}}([\cdot\alpha])$ as a diagonal matrix representation in $Mat_{[K[\alpha]:K]}(\overline{K[\alpha]})$    i.e. $mat_{\mathcal{B}}([\cdot\alpha])=diag(\lambda_i\in\overline{K[\alpha]})$. Now Given $w\in K[\alpha]$ then $w=ev_{\alpha}(Q(X))=Q(\alpha)$ for some $Q(X)\in K[X]$ . We compute: $$mat_{\mathcal{B}}([\cdot w])=mat_{\mathcal{B}}([\cdot Q(\alpha)])=mat_{\mathcal{B}}(Q([\cdot\alpha]))=Q(mat_{\mathcal{B}}([\cdot\alpha]))$$ (since matrix representation of sum and product IS the sum and product of matrix representation). But as $mat_{\mathcal{B}}([\cdot\alpha])$ is diagonal this means $Q(mat_{\mathcal{B}}([\cdot\alpha]))$ is diagonal, hence $mat_{\mathcal{B}}([\cdot w])$ is diagonal which is equivalent to say $P_{min,[\cdot w],K}(X)=P_{min,w,K}(X)$ has only simple roots which shows $w$ is separable.

Now you can show by induction that $K[a_1,...,a_n]$ is separable iff a_1,...,a_n are separable elements.